# Script para Windows que distinga por IP

Tags: windows, script, ip, línea-de-comandos

Necesito vuestra ayuda ya que me estoy volviendo loco para crear un script que al iniciar sesión se ejecute en todos los puestos del dominio y que modifique el nombre de la Organización en Windows en función de la dirección IP del PC. El problema lo tengo para conseguir que si la dirección IP del PC está en este rango

10.51.40.0/22

Ejecute esto

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v    RegisteredOrganization /t REG_SZ /d "Entidad 1" /f
```

Y si no está comprendida en estè rango ejecute esto:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v RegisteredOrganization /t REG_SZ /d "Entidad 2" /f
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un script en lenguage VBS, tendrás que guardarlo con extensión vbs y ejecutarlo como administrador con el comando **cscript** para que pueda modificar dicha clave de registro.

Es un pequeño script que primero detecta en que versión de Windows se está ejecutando para poder obtener correctamente todas las IPs que tiene la máquina.

Una vez recogidas las IPs de la máquina comprueba si dicha IP esta en el rango indicado o no, con la función IPEnRed(IP, "10.51.40.0/22").

En tu caso puedes tener problemas si un equipo tiene más de una ip, ya que modificará tantas veces el registro como IPs tenga la máquina. En dicho caso NO deberías utilizar el else en el If de IPEnRed, y montar tantos Ifs de IPEnRed como necesites (uno para cada red).

```
Option Explicit
Dim winVer

Dim ip, IPs, ArrIPs
Dim i, extraCommand

' Obtenemos version del sistema operativo
winVer = myGetWinVersion()

Set IPs = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

If winVer(0) > 6 Then
    ' Windows Vista y siguientes 
    GetIPs(IPs)
Else
    ' Windows XP
    GetIPs_XP(IPs)
End If

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

ArrIPs = IPs.ToArray()

For Each IP in ArrIPs
    'WScript.echo IP & " - " & IpEnRed(IP, "10.51.40.0/22")
    If IpEnRed(IP, "10.51.40.0/22") Then
        'Empresa 1
        objShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization", "Entidad 1", "REG_SZ"
    Else
        'Empresa 2
        objShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization", "Entidad 2", "REG_SZ"
    End If
Next

Set objShell = Nothing

' Devuelve un array con la version del windows separado por .
Function myGetWinVersion

    Dim strComputer
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim num
    Dim oss, os
    Dim arr(4), cad

    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set oss = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

    For Each os in oss
        cad = Split(os.Version, ".")
    Next

    i = 0
    For each num in cad
        arr(i) = num
        i=i+1
    Next

    myGetWinVersion = arr

End Function

Sub GetIPs_XP(IPs)
    Dim strComputer
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim colAdapters
    Dim objAdapter

    strComputer = "."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
    For Each objAdapter In colAdapters

        If not IsNull(objAdapter.IPAddress(0))  Then
            If objAdapter.IPAddress(0) <> "127.0.0.1" Then IPs.Add objAdapter.IPAddress(0)
        End If

    Next

    Set colAdapters = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Sub

Sub GetIPs(IPs)
' Este funciona para Windows 10
    Dim strComputer
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim colAdapters
    Dim objAdapter

    strComputer = "."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "!\\" & strComputer & "\ROOT\standardcimv2")
    Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from MSFT_NetIPAddress")
    For Each objAdapter In colAdapters

        'Wscript.Echo "IP " & objAdapter.IPv4Address & " - Interfaz " & objAdapter.InterfaceIndex
        If not IsNull(objAdapter.IPv4Address) Then
            If objAdapter.IPv4Address <> "127.0.0.1" Then  IPs.Add objAdapter.IPv4Address
        End If

    Next

    Set colAdapters = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Sub

Function IpEnRed(IP, Red)

    Dim minRed, maxRed, IpBin

    minRed = INET_NTOA(CIDR2IP(Red, false))
    maxRed = INET_NTOA(CIDR2IP(Red, true))
    IpBin = INET_NTOA(IP)

    If ( ( IpBin > minRed ) and ( IpBin < maxRed ) ) Then
        IpEnRed = True
    Else
        IpEnRed = False
    End If

End Function


'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232835/ip-range-caclulator-from-ip-address-netmask-using-vbscript
Function CIDR2IP(ip, high)
    Dim highs, lows, byte0, byte1, byte2, byte3, Mask, bytes, rangelow, rangehigh, iplow, iphigh

    highs = "11111111111111111111111111111111"
    lows = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    byte0 = Dec2bin(Split(ip, ".")(0))
    byte1 = Dec2bin(Split(ip, ".")(1))
    byte2 = Dec2bin(Split(ip, ".")(2))
    byte3 = Dec2bin(Split(Split(ip, ".")(3), "/")(0))
    Mask = Split(Split(ip, ".")(3), "/")(1)
    bytes = byte0 & byte1 & byte2 & byte3
    rangelow = Left(bytes, Mask) & Right(lows, 32 - Mask)
    rangehigh = Left(bytes, Mask) & Right(highs, 32 - Mask)
    iplow = bin2ip(Left(bytes, Mask) & Right(lows, 32 - Mask))
    iphigh = bin2ip(Left(bytes, Mask) & Right(highs, 32 - Mask))
    If high Then
        CIDR2IP = iphigh
    Else
        CIDR2IP = iplow
    End If
End Function

Function Dec2bin(dec)
    Dim bin, m, x
    Const maxpower = 7
    Const length = 8
    bin = ""
    x = cLng(dec)
    For m = maxpower To 0 Step -1
        If x And (2 ^ m) Then
            bin = bin + "1"
        Else
            bin = bin + "0"
        End If
    Next
    Dec2bin = bin
End Function

Function bin2ip(strbin)
    Dim ip0, ip1, ip2, ip3

    ip0 = C2dec(Mid(strbin, 1, 8))
    ip1 = C2dec(Mid(strbin, 9, 8))
    ip2 = C2dec(Mid(strbin, 17, 8))
    ip3 = C2dec(Mid(strbin, 25, 8))
    'combines all of the bytes into a single string
    bin2ip = ip0 & "." & ip1 & "." & ip2 & "." & ip3 
End Function

Function C2dec(strbin)
    Dim length, dec, x, binval, temp

    length = Len(strbin)
    dec = 0
    For x = 1 To length
        binval = 2 ^ (length - x)
        temp = Mid(strbin, x, 1)
        If temp = "1" Then dec = dec + binval
    Next
    C2dec = dec
End Function

Function INET_NTOA(ip)
    Dim ip0, ip1, ip2, ip3, urlobfs

    ip0 = Split(ip, ".")(0)
    ip1 = Split(ip, ".")(1)
    ip2 = Split(ip, ".")(2)
    ip3 = Split(ip, ".")(3)
    urlobfs = 0
    urlobfs = ip0 * 256
    urlobfs = urlobfs + ip1
    urlobfs = urlobfs * 256
    urlobfs = urlobfs + ip2
    urlobfs = urlobfs * 256
    urlobfs = urlobfs + ip3
    INET_NTOA = urlobfs
End Function
```

Comment: Funciona de lujo. ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: Excelente, no te olvides de marcarla entonces como respuesta a tu pregunta ;-)